# Avoiding Unexpected Token illegal while string assignment

Tags: javascript, c#-4.0, razor

I am pretty new to web development and trying to achieve the following

I have a c# string which has html tags (Its a cshtml page  - ASP.net Webpages ):

```
var htmlStr="div style="text-align: center;"><i style="font-size: 10pt;"><b><u>some text&nbsp;</u></b></i></div><div style="text-align: center;"><i><b><u><br></u></b></i></div><div style="text-align: center;"><i><b><u><br></u></b></i></div><div style="font-weight: normal; text-align: center; font-style: normal;"><br></div>" ;
```

Then in the JavaScript i use this as follows :

```
 var jStr = '@htmlStr';
```

I get the following error

****"Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected token ILLEGAL"****

I am i assuming the string is not getting assigned properly. Please help me out here  and let me know what is the proper way of doing this ???

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution  with escape function :

```
var jStr = escape('@htmlStr');
```